# Excel Webbrowser Scrolling within a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform and added a webbrowser control.  I am loading PDF images into the webbrowser control on the userform.  What i would like to do is add a button to scroll the webbrowser downwards so i can see the next page of the pdf.

Comment: How are the PDF documents being displayed?  In Adobe Reader?

Comment: Not sure why do you want a button to scroll. You can use the wheel of the mouse to scroll up and down.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I guess he is using the `.Navigate` Ex: `WebBrowser1.Navigate "C:\Sample.pdf"`

Comment: I cannot use the wheel as i am vnc to tablet sorry did not mention earlier, was just trying to easier solution then 2-finger scroll as it creates more issues then solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.Navigate` with `#page=` to move to the relevant page. Here is an example in which we move to page no 2.

```
Dim FName As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Replace this with the relevant file name
    FName = "C:\Sample.pdf"

    WebBrowser1.Navigate "file:///" & FName
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim PageNo As Long

    PageNo = 2

    '~~> I noticed that if I do not include
    '~~> this line then the next .Navigate doesn't work
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "About:Blank"
    Wait 1 '<~~ Wait for a second

    WebBrowser1.Navigate ("file:///" & FName & "#page=" & PageNo)
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth thanks for the help, unfourtanetly i get error page2 not found.  To be clear I am opening a pdf file which is 6 pages long from my userform

Comment: Siddharth, absolutely Brilliant, this is exactly what i was trying to acchomplish ( i had Fname in wrong place)